# laravel error cannot convert to string

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 and have a problem.

My code is;

```
$sts = STSMember::find($member_id)->join('rating', 's_t_s_members.member_id', '=', 'rating.member_id');
```

But I get the following error

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string'.

How to get member_id from two table?

Answer (score 0):

`find` returns a model instance, you need either:

```
STSMember::where("id","=",$member_id)->join('rating', 's_t_s_members.member_id', '=', 'rating.member_id')->get();
```

Or ideally:

```
class STSMember extends Model {
      //Other model code

      public function rating() {
             return $this->belongsTo(Rating::class);
      }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
 STMember::with("rating")->find($member_id);
```

Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships